# Doubt in graph theory about planarity

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

A graph is said to be non-planar when it contains a subgraph isomorphic or homeomorphic to $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$ or the graph itself is convertible to any of these two graphs by homomorphic operations. Is this statement true? Can someone please provide a reference?

Answer (score 1):

Google: "planar graph" -> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Kuratowski's_and_Wagner's_theorems)
What you are looking for is known as Wagner's theorem.

Google: "Wagner's theorem" -> [University of Chicago](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2016/REUPapers/Tamar-Mattis.pdf)
I haven't really read the paper and the author, Squid Tamar-Mattis, isn't googable that easily, but the paper was submitted to [the Chicago REU 2016](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2016/REUPapers/Tamar-Mattis.pdf), so I would give it some credibility.

Wagner's theorem is proved there based on Kuratowski's theorem which is also proved there. I think the basic idea is that $K_{3,3}$ and $K_5$ are non-planar (this should be clear), all non-planar graphs have $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$ as minors and if G has no non-planar minors, it must be planar.